# Unit Testing - updating model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to write a test to verify that when I update my user object the correct fields are being updated.  My unit test looks like:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldUpdateExistingEmployee()
{
    var employees = new Employee[]
    {
        new Employee()
        {
            EmployeeId = 1,
            FirstName = "Johhn",
            LastName = "Smiths",
            Email = "John.Smith1@Illinois.gov",
            IsActive = true
         }
    };

    var mockContext = new Mock<SqlContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(e => e.Employees).ReturnsDbSet(employees);
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Employees.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
         .Returns<object[]>(
                  ids => employees.FirstOrDefault(d => d.EmployeeId == (int)ids[0]));

    var sut = new EmployeeRepository(mockContext.Object);

    var employeeToUpdate = new Employee
    {
        EmployeeId = 1,
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Smith",
        Email = "John.Smith@Illinois.gov",
        IsActive = true
    };

    sut.Save(employeeToUpdate);

    Assert.That(employees.First().FirstName, Is.EqualTo(employeeToUpdate.FirstName));
    Assert.That(employees.First().LastName, Is.EqualTo(employeeToUpdate.LastName));
    Assert.That(employees.First().Email, Is.EqualTo(employeeToUpdate.Email));
}
```

My repository looks like:

```
public void Save(Employee employee)
{
    if (employee.EmployeeId > 0)
    {
        Employee dbEmployee = Context.Employees.Find(employee.EmployeeId);
        Context.Entry(dbEmployee).CurrentValues.SetValues(employee);
    }
    else
    {
        Context.Employees.Add(employee);
    }

    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is when I get to `Context.Entry(dbEmployee).CurrentValues.SetValues(employee);` in my repository I get the following error: `Member 'CurrentValues' cannot be called for the entity of type 'Employee' because the entity does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet<Employee>.`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx), you should change:

```
Employee dbEmployee = Context.Employees.Find(employee.EmployeeId);
Context.Entry(dbEmployee).CurrentValues.SetValues(employee);
```

to:

```
Context.Employees.Attach(employee)
```

Then you should change your assert to verify that the `Attach` method was called with `employeeToUpdate`.(you hide the `DBSet<>` in the method `ReturnsDbSet` so I couldn't add an example...)

One more thing, I think you should take a look in [this code snippet](http://aikmeng.com/post/62817541825/how-to-mock-dbcontext-and-dbset-with-moq-for-unit) which shows the right way to mock `DBContext` and `DBSet<>` using `Moq`. Or [read this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx)

Comment: I'll give this a shot.  I found the `ReturnsDbSet` extension from http://codethug.com/2015/03/20/mocking-dbset/  It's the same as the msdn article unless you see some problems with it?

Comment: @Andrew I don't see any problem in the link.... Use `CreateMockSet<T>` for an access to the `DBSet<>` (use the `Returns` instead of `ReturnsDbSet`) and then verify the `Attach` was called instead of the multiple asserts

Comment: So because I call `Attach` when `Context.SaveChanges()` is called the object will be updated?  Do I still need the `Context.Employees.Find(employee.EmployeeId)` line?

Comment: @Andrew Based on the article you don't need it any more...(I wrote it in my answer)

Comment: Sorry, have been busy and didn't get a chance to try it out until now.  This doesn't work.  It attaches the entity so the unit test will pass, but when I actually call the method in my service (not unit test) it doesn't save the changes to the database.  Is there a `setup` method I need to call for `mockContext` that will attach the entity?

Comment: @Andrew I read again the article in my answer, the reason for the new problem is: "Note that no changes will be made to the database if SaveChanges is called without doing any other manipulation of the attached entity". So the easiest solution I can offer you is to add `context.Entry(dbEmployee).State = EntityState.Modified; ` after `Context.Employees.Attach(employee)`.

Comment: Do you think this is the correct way to update the entity though?  I feel like it's a work around to get the unit test working?

Comment: @Andrew why do you feel it is a workaround? In the article (in my answer) `Microsoft` argues under the title of "Insert or update pattern" to do something like:`context.Entry(blog).State = blog.BlogId == 0 ? 
                                   EntityState.Added : 
                                   EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges(); ` for a method similar to yours...

Comment: I don't know, I guess it just wasn't what I was expecting.  I did change my repository to just have `context.Entry(employee) = EntityState.Modified;` and removed the `Context.Employees.Attach(employee)` (I didn't need this).  Then in my unit test I just changed the verify statement to `mockContext.Verify(e => e.SaveChanges(), Times.Once());`

Comment: Hello - your link is dead http://aikmeng.com/post/62817541825/how-to-mock-dbcontext-and-dbset-with-moq-for-unit

Comment: Hello @Bartosz  I don't remember what was written in the link but in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641349/4332059) I showed an easy way to mock using moq which is saves you from writing a boilerplate code.