# How to write this EF Mock setup code as a reusable Generic Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, generics, moq

I am using moq, ef 6 and xunit. I find myself writing this code over and over and thought maybe I could make it into a generic method but having some trouble.

```
public static void CreateSalesMock(List<Sale> sales, Mock<DatabaseContext> dbContextMock)
{
    var data = sales.AsQueryable();

    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Sale>>();
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Sale>>()
           .Setup(x => x.Provider)
           .Returns(data.Provider);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Sale>>()
           .Setup(x => x.Expression)
           .Returns(data.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Sale>>()
           .Setup(x => x.ElementType)
           .Returns(data.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<Sale>>()
           .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
           .Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

    dbContextMock.Setup(x => x.Sales).Returns(mockSet.Object);
}
```

Now I have many other tables in my database so if I could write one method that would take in a list of that data and set it up so I can mock query through it would be great.

```
public static void CreateMockSet<T, TA, TB>(T dataList, TA model, 
    Func<TB> lambda, Mock<DatabaseContext> dbContextMock) 
     where T : List<T>
     where TA: Mock<DbSet<TA>>
{
    var data = dataList.AsQueryable();

    model.As<IQueryable<T>>()
         .Setup(x => x.Provider)
         .Returns(data.Provider);
    model.As<IQueryable<T>>()
         .Setup(x => x.Expression)
         .Returns(data.Expression);
    model.As<IQueryable<T>>()
         .Setup(x => x.ElementType)
         .Returns(data.ElementType);
    model.As<IQueryable<T>>()
         .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
         .Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

    dbContextMock.Setup(x => lambda);
}
```

So far I have that but I am not sure if that will work or not. I am stuck passing in the "lambda" part(`x => x.Sales` for example) so I can't even test it.

Comment: I think you want to change the `where` constraint to introduce an interface: `where T : List<IBase>`.

Comment: I'd recommend a look at the Builder Pattern see https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/07/15/flexible-and-expressive-unit-tests-with-the-builder-pattern/

Comment: @ToddSprang I am not sure what IBase would be. Could you give more of an example

Answer (score 11):

Tim Larson already offered a great solution for this boilerplate code in [his blog](http://codethug.com/2015/03/20/mocking-dbset/):

```
public static class DbSetMocking
{
    private static Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateMockSet<T>(IQueryable<T> data)
            where T : class
    {
        var queryableData = data.AsQueryable();
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider)
                .Returns(queryableData.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression)
                .Returns(queryableData.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType)
                .Returns(queryableData.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
                .Returns(queryableData.GetEnumerator());
        return mockSet;
    }

    public static IReturnsResult<TContext> ReturnsDbSet<TEntity, TContext>(
            this IReturns<TContext, DbSet<TEntity>> setup,
            TEntity[] entities)
        where TEntity : class
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> mockSet;
        return ReturnsDbSet(setup, entities, out mockSet);
    }

    public static IReturnsResult<TContext> ReturnsDbSet<TEntity, TContext>(
            this IReturns<TContext, DbSet<TEntity>> setup,
            IQueryable<TEntity> entities)
        where TEntity : class
        where TContext : DbContext
    {

        Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> mockSet;
        return ReturnsDbSet(setup, entities, out mockSet);
    }

    public static IReturnsResult<TContext> ReturnsDbSet<TEntity, TContext>(
            this IReturns<TContext, DbSet<TEntity>> setup,
            IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        where TEntity : class
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> mockSet;
        return ReturnsDbSet(setup, entities, out mockSet);
    }

    public static IReturnsResult<TContext> ReturnsDbSet<TEntity, TContext>(
    this IReturns<TContext, DbSet<TEntity>> setup,
    TEntity[] entities, out Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> mockSet)
        where TEntity : class
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        mockSet = CreateMockSet(entities.AsQueryable());
        return setup.Returns(mockSet.Object);
    }

    public static IReturnsResult<TContext> ReturnsDbSet<TEntity, TContext>(
            this IReturns<TContext, DbSet<TEntity>> setup,
            IQueryable<TEntity> entities, out Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> mockSet)
        where TEntity : class
        where TContext : DbContext
    {

        mockSet = CreateMockSet(entities);
        return setup.Returns(mockSet.Object);
    }

    public static IReturnsResult<TContext> ReturnsDbSet<TEntity, TContext>(
    this IReturns<TContext, DbSet<TEntity>> setup,
    IEnumerable<TEntity> entities, out Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> mockSet)
        where TEntity : class
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        mockSet = CreateMockSet(entities.AsQueryable());
        return setup.Returns(mockSet.Object);
    }

}
```

Then in the UT you use it as the following:

```
var context = new Mock<DatabaseContext>();
context.setup(x => x.Sales).ReturnsDbSet(new List<Sale>(){put here the items..});
```

**Edit**

I updated the code. Now there are 3 more overloads which allows verification on `DbSet<T>` property:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var sales = new List<Sale>
        {
            new Sale() {id = 1},
            new Sale() {id = 6},
            new Sale() {id = 5},
            new Sale() {id = 4},
            new Sale() {id = 3},
            new Sale() {id = 2}
        };
        var fakeContest = new Mock<SalesContext>();
        Mock<DbSet<Sale>> fakeSet;
        fakeContest.Setup(context => context.Sales).ReturnsDbSet(sales, out fakeSet);

        var itemsToRemove = sales.Where(sale => sale.id%2 == 0);


        fakeContest.Object.Sales.RemoveRange(itemsToRemove);


        fakeSet.Verify(set => set.RemoveRange(itemsToRemove));

    }
```

Comment: Cool, this is what I was looking for but what happens if I need to add more Setups to the Mockset? For instance I want to see if RemoveRange was called so before I just ran the verify on SalesMock and that worked. but now I don't have it I am not sure what to do. I tried to do the verify through the dbContext.Verify(x => x.Sales.RemoveRange(...)) but that always fails.

Comment: @chobo2 Don't do such a thing. `context.Sales` is a `List` of `Sales` which is a BCL collection. You shouldn't mock a BCL collections. Instead of doing so verify that the list no longer contains the elements.

Comment: How do I test the list no longer contains the elements? I tried that first but my unit test side never seemed to have them removed. Like in my service I saw them being removed but when I looked at my original collection they where all still there.

Comment: @chobo2 my fault, I wasn't aware that `DbSet<T>` has `RemoveRange` method. I updated my answer with a solution....