# Moq: Mock SetUp method only returns null during test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I just added dependency inject into my application, and would like to run mock test on my methods to ensure they are working properly.

I have a domain class `Person` with the following properties:

```
public class Person : DomainBase
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public char Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB {get; set; }
}
```

I have a partial `manager` class that is shared with other domain type mangers:

```
public partial class Manager : IManager1
{
    private IHiveTiesContext _ctx; 
    public Manager(IHiveTiesContext context)
    {
        _ctx = context;
    }
}
```

The interface `IManager1` was extracted from my `PersonManager` class and contains all need methods.

My `PersonManager` `CreatePerson()` method is being called and tested:

```
public partial class Manager : IManager1
{
    public Person CreatePerson(string fn, string ln, DateTime dob, char gender, Guid RId)
    {
       var _person =_ctx.People.Add(new Person
       {  
          FirstName = fn,
          LastName = ln,
          DOB = dob,
          Gender = gender,
          RowId = RId});

          _ctx.SaveChanges();
          return _person;
        }
    }  
}
```

My context follows and once again I extracted an interface `IHiveTiesContext` from it.

```
public class HiveTiesContext : DbContext, IHiveTiesContext
{
    public HiveTiesContext() :  base("hiveties")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<HiveTiesContext>(null);
    }

    public virtual IDbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I am trying to test `CreatePerson` like this:

```
public class PersonManagerMockTest
{
    private static Guid personGuid;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Init(TestContext test)
    {
        personGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddNewPerson()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Person>>();

        var mockContext = new Mock<IHiveTiesContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.People)
            .Returns(mockDbSet.Object);

        var manager = new Manager(mockContext.Object);

        //Assert
        var _person = manager.CreatePerson("Winston", "Gabriel", DateTime.Now, 'M', personGuid);

        if(_person == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("NOT WORKING MAN!!!!");
        }

        var personid = mockContext.Object.People.Single(x => x.RowId == personGuid).Id;

        //Act
        mockDbSet.Verify(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Person>()));
        mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges());
    }
}
```

My problem is that my `Person` object is never created, that is, it always returns a `null` value and the exception is always thrown. I believe I am telling it to return a `Person` entity, but I am not sure where I am going wrong. This is my first time using `Moq` and running `Mock Unit Tests`.

I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: You have to mock setup the CreatePerson method. something like mockContent.Setup(m => m.CreatePerson(fn, ln, dob, gender, RId)).Returns(new Person){ //your object here });

Comment: I'll give that try @Chris

Comment: Kindly move down this code part `var manager = new Manager(mockContext.Object);` after you created the Person object.

Comment: I am unable to move that code after the method call because it needs to be declared first. @Chris

Comment: Oh yeah! my bad. Why don't you create a function that saves a Person object in IHiveTiesContext? I will post my solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You didn't set any behavior on the `Add` method of `mockDbSet`.

Add:(This line initialize the method to return the given person)

```
mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Person>()))
         .Returns <Person>(p => p);
```

Between the mocks:

```
var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Person>>();
mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Person>()))
         .Returns<Person>(p => p);

var mockContext = new Mock<IHiveTiesContext>();
mockContext.Setup(x => x.People)
           .Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
...
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, now my only problem is that I can not get an Id off the person I created using the line                                                              `var personid = mockContext.Object.People.Single(x => x.RowId == personGuid).Id;`                                                                                                   The `personid` returns as `0` even though the object is created, do you know why? @OldFox

Comment: @AaronLWG, It happens because `mockContext.Object.People` is a mock object... use the `CreateMockSet` from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33641349/4332059) to create your `DbSet` then add `Callback` to the setup I offered, in this callback you'll put the given person in the list.

Comment: To be honest, that is a bit above my ability level, so I do not really understand. I was hoping to find a way of accessing the `Id` property off the mocked `Person` object, but not too sure if that will work either @OldFox

Answer (score 2):

I created a new signature/function in IHiveTiesContext to save Person object. (It's up to you now how you implement the interface).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SampleManager
{
    public class Manager : IManager
    {
        private IHiveTiesContext _ctx;
        public Manager(IHiveTiesContext context)
        {
            _ctx = context;
        }

        public Person CreatePerson(string fn, string ln, DateTime dob, char gender, Guid RId)
        {
            var person = _ctx.Save(fn, ln);
            return person;
        }
    }


    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public char Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public Guid RowId { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IManager
    {
        Person CreatePerson(string fn, string ln, DateTime dob, char gender, Guid RId);
    }

    public interface IHiveTiesContext
    {
        Person Save(string fn, string ln);
    }
}

/// <summary>
    ///A test for CreatePerson
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    public void CreatePersonTest1()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IHiveTiesContext>();
        //fill up your expected object
        mock.Setup(m => m.Save(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new Person { FirstName = "William" });

        Manager t = new Manager(mock.Object);
        var results = t.CreatePerson(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<Char>(), It.IsAny<Guid>());

        Assert.AreEqual("William", results.FirstName);
    }
```