# Moq: How to retrieve ID of mocked object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, entity-framework-6, moq

I have successfully created a mocked `Person` object and I am now trying to use my `AddChild()` method to add a child to the object via its' Id. My test looks like this:

```
public class PersonManagerMockTest
{
    private static Guid personGuid;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Init(TestContext test)
    {
        personGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void AddNewPerson()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Person>>();
        mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Person>()))
            .Returns<Person>(p => p);

        var mockContext = new Mock<IHiveTiesContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.People)
            .Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
        var manager = new Manager(mockContext.Object);

        //Assert
        var _person = manager.CreatePerson("Winston", "Gabriel", DateTime.Now, 'M', personGuid);

        var fatherid = mockDbSet.Object.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RowId == personGuid).Id;
        manager.AddChild(new Person
        {
            FirstName = "Aaron",
            LastName = "Gabriel",
            DOB = new DateTime(1991, 01, 16),
            FavoriteColor = "Red",
            FatherId = fatherid,
        });

        //Act
        mockDbSet.Verify(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Person>()), Times.Once);
        mockContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

The mocked `Person` object is successfully created, but the problem comes from this statement:

```
var fatherid = mockDbSet.Object.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RowId == personGuid).Id;
```

I am not sure how to retrieve the `Id` from the mocked `Person` object, and as I thought this statement returned `0` for `fatherid` meaning that it is `null`. This is my first time running mocks, so I am still learning. Any suggestions on how to retrieve the `Id` from this mocked `Person` object? 
I will appreciate all suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `CreateMockSet` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33641349/4332059).

Change:

```
var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Person>>();
mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Person>()))
         .Returns<Person>(p => p);
```

To:

```
var persons = new List<Person>();

var mockDbSet = CreateMockSet(persons.AsQueryable());
mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Person>()))
         .Callback<Person>(persons.Add)
         .Returns <Person>(p => p);
```

The `Callback` method populate the `persons` list with the new `Person` instance.

The `CreateMockSet()` create `Mock<DbSet<Person>>` with the return setup of `persons`(on `mockDbSet.Object`)

Comment: How does this allow me access the `Id` property on the mocked `Person` object? @OldFox

Comment: `mockDbSet.Object.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RowId == personGuid)` will return the `Person` instance where `x.RowId == personGuid`.

Comment: I am guessing I have to create a new method for `CreateMockSet` within my test class? also what is the significance of this method and what should this method contain within its body? @OldFox

Comment: Well, no you don't need to... I suggest you to read my answer in the link. It's a generic a class with several extension methods which help dealing with entity framework in UTs(IMO anyone use entity framework and has UTs must have this class in his UT's infrastructure). You just need to turn this method to be public.

Comment: I did, my only problem is that I still do not have access to this `CreateMockSet` method. Is it that you want me to change my test class into a generic class? and IMO? what does this acronym mean? @OldFox

Comment: I said in the last comment "You just need to turn this method to be public".... you don't have to change your test class to generic(just add the class into the test dll, then you'll be able to use it anywhere...) the class in the link is generic --> to be reusable. IMO = In my opinion.

Comment: How do I add my class into the test dll? and where is this even located? I have never used it before so thats why I am a bit confused. @OldFox

Comment: test dll is the compilation result of your test project... copy-past the class into the test project.

Comment: I did everything you said and I still cannot get that method to work. I add the entire generic class from your post as a new class in the same test project and made both the class and the method public. Now in my other class where I am actually running the mocks cannot access that method @OldFox

Comment: No, you didn't do everything I said: "You just need to turn this method to be public"

Comment: Ok I found the error, because the class and method are both static I needed to access the method as `DbSetMocking.CreateDbMock()`. @OldFox

Comment: you could have done this...  mockSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<ValuationCompany>()))
                    .Callback<ValuationCompany>(data.Add)
                    .Returns<ValuationCompany>(p =>
                    {
                        p.Id = 23;  // assing whatever you want here.
                        return p;
                    });

Comment: @Choco I think that you didn't understand the OP's problem... his problem occurred from creating the mock in a wrong way + `static` method....

Answer (score 2):

Making OldFoxes answer more clear for the innate!

```
 mockSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<ValuationCompany>()))
                .Callback<ValuationCompany>(data.Add)
                .Returns<ValuationCompany>(p =>
                {
                    p.Id = 23;  // Assign whatever you want here.
                    return p;
                });
```

Comment: and you may have to mark the ValuationCompany property as virtual in the DBContext.

Answer (score 0):

MockObjects don't have logic and cannot generate Id.

Since DbSet is mocked you have to tell it what it should do. So try to change the setup of DbSet like this:

```
var newId = 42;
var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<Person>>();
mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Person>()))
         .Returns(newId);
```

In this way you are telling to Moq that when someone calls DbSet.Add whatever person it is, it must return 42.

Comment: Ok thank you for the feedback, I will have to research how to do what you suggested @ema

Comment: Is the Add method of the DbSet that returns the Id of the new Person? In that case is easy.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you said, can you please repeat? @ema

Comment: If I understand, the method Add of the class DbSet returns the Id of the newly created Person. Is that correct?

Comment: It should be, I don't see why it isn't doing so though @ema