# Testing a windows authenticated Action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for the action methods and get the following error in the Action method.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No Entity Framework provider found for the
>   ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make
>   sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of
>   the application config file.

**Method**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var user = db.UserRight.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserCode == User.Identity.Name);
        ViewBag.UserName = user.UserName;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

**Test Method**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Home()
    {
        var controller = new HomeController();
        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
    }
```

How can i pass the value of user from the test method so that the test do not throw any errors.

Comment: Use moq to mock your DAL, then inject that fake object into the controller. use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636443/how-to-write-this-ef-mock-setup-code-as-a-reusable-generic-boilerplate/33641349#33641349)  to reduce boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the <entityFramework ...> section from web.config in the app.config file of your test project.

Comment: After adding that even the simplest unit test is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your question has already been answered, I just want to give a bit of advice - you should almost never try to test your actions. This is is bad paractice - difficult to achieve (all the mocking you should take into consideration) and brings little value. Have your business logic in services/helpers instead and test them. So in your case I would rather have:

```
var user = UserService.GetUserByName(User.Identity.Name);
```

And then I will have a unit test for that service method.

Comment: I am actually trying to learn to add unit test for methods. I was following a tutorial on how to write unit tests and was stuck here..