# How to fake or mock user logging in (authentication) with ASP.NET MVC for functional testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, automated-tests, asp.net-identity

I'm building a custom permissions system for ASP.NET MVC, because the authorization system that comes with MVC just isn't flexible enough for our needs. This includes an MVC area that's packaged into a DLL along with views, CSS and JavaScript. I have unit tests already, but now I'm trying to create functional tests through the browser. These functional tests would be run locally from my computer or on a continuous integration server.

The permissions system I'm building doesn't do authentication. It just handles authorization. Ideally I'd like to fake the user log-ins for each test. I would like to create a user session from arbitrary usernames and passwords instead of keeping a separate table of users with their passwords, and authenticating against that.

I tried setting the `GenericPrincipal` object in the session in my `AccountController`, and then setting `HttpContext.Current.User` before each request, but the request is always seen as unauthenticated:

**AccountController**

```csharp
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);

            // Add the fake user to the current session so Global.asax can set
            // the user on the current HttpContext to this mock object. (See
            // Global.asax, Application_AcquireRequestState)
            HttpContext.Session["CurrentUser"] = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(model.Username), new string[0]);

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                return Redirect(ReturnUrl);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Username or Password is incorrect");

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```csharp
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            // Try to get the mock user from the session, which is set in
            // AccountController.Login...
            HttpContext.Current.User = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] as IPrincipal;
        }
    }
}
```

I created a custom `Authorize` attribute to be used in my MVC Controllers:

```csharp
public class PermissionLevelAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated || CurrentPrincipal == null)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            return;
        }

        // Custom permissions logic...
    }
}
```

Example usage of this attribute in a Controller:

```csharp
public class BlogPostsController : Controller
{
    [PermissionLevel(Roles="Blogs.Posts.Edit.Update")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I do this, the `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` property is always false, and it bails out of the `OnAuthorization` method.

---

#### How do I fake or mock a user login in ASP.NET MVC so it creates the `HttpContext.Current.Session` object and sets `HttpContext.Current.User`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873263/testing-a-windows-authenticated-action-method. This question has comments which could help answer your question. You should use Moq to achieve the task.

Comment: Actually I figured out my problem. It was a clean install of ASP.NET MVC5, which by default uses OWIN middleware for authentication instead of Forms Authentication. I still had a bunch of OWIN authentication config settings cluttering up my Web.config file, specifically the `<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />` tag in the system.web/modules element in Web.config.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your tests? I have same problem as you, and editing web.config did not helped.

Comment: @PiotrM: I had to do a little more than edit web.config. I'll post a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: @PiotrM: I just posted my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't really create a "mock" user so much as it creates a fake user and doesn't check the username and password. To do this, you'll need to make two major changes:

1. Rewrite `AccountController` so it doesn't actually check the username and password

   ```
   [Authorize]
   public class AccountController : Controller
   {
       //
       // GET: /Account/Login
       [AllowAnonymous]
       public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
       {
           ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
           return View();
       }

       //
       // POST: /Account/Login
       [HttpPost]
       [AllowAnonymous]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string ReturnUrl)
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);

               if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                   return Redirect(ReturnUrl);

               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
           }

           ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Username or Password is incorrect");

           return View(model);
       }

       //
       // GET: /Account/LogOff
       public ActionResult LogOff()
       {
           FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Remove or comment out the OWIN related config settings in Web.config:

   ```xml
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <modules>
         <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />-->
       </modules>
     </system.webServer>
     <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <!--<dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>-->
       </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>
   </configuration>
   ```

This will allow you to log in as any arbitrary user with any password.

**Important:** I wouldn't do this for a production version of a web application, obviously. I was building an MVC Area as a NuGet package and installing that package on a clean MVC project to write automated tests against the integrated NuGet package and MVC application. That's why I was able to use this solution.

Comment: Yeah, that is clever solution but as you mentioned, not possible for production. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Check out my question, this is exactly what I'm struggling with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588659/how-can-i-test-methods-which-needs-user-to-be-logged/35600351#35600351

Comment: Im not sure you should be changing anything about the code so that it works with testing :s