# How can I test methods which needs user to be logged

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit

I'm testing some code which needs user to be logged in. When I'm trying to log in with `AccountController`, it's looks like everything is working, but at `AccountController` `(IPrincipal) User` is still null. How can I properly log in (or better, can I mock it somehow)?

```
public async Task SetupAsync()
        {
            var context = new DataContext();
            var manager = new UserManager(new UserStore(context));
            var accountController = new AccountController(manager);
            var mockAuthenticationManager = new Mock<IAuthenticationManager>();
            mockAuthenticationManager.Setup(am => am.SignOut());
            mockAuthenticationManager.Setup(am => am.SignIn());
            accountController.AuthenticationManager = mockAuthenticationManager.Object;
            var user = new LoginViewModel
            {
                Email = "user@wp.pl",
                Password = "useruser",
                RememberMe = false
            };
            if (manager.FindByEmail("user@wp.pl") == null)
            {
                await manager.CreateAsync(new User { Email = "user@wp.pl", UserName = "user@wp.pl" }, "useruser");
            }
            await accountController.Login(user, "home/index");
            _calendarController = new CalendarController(context);
        }
```

Here I got User null exception:

```
public ClaimsPrincipal CurrentUser
        {
            get { return new ClaimsPrincipal((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)this.User); }
        }
```

Edit: At return line, I have still `User` property null. This is sample from `AccountController`:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("index", "calendar");
            }
```

Comment: can you please give the code for the source controller? also, what testing do you want to do? unit testing right?

Comment: Yes, it should be unit testing. Now, it is mess with some integration tests behaviour. Ideally I wold like mock context (i will use Effor framework for that) and test integration later.

Comment: Also, maybe I should add: When I'm using website manually, everything is working, User is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own, probably not elegant solution but I'm happy anyway. @andreasnico your answer helped, thanks.

I'm mocking my custom ClaimsPrincipal, and setting up UserId - that's what I really needed.

```
var mockCp = new Mock<IClaimsPrincipal>();
mockCp.SetupGet(cp => cp.UserId).Returns(user.Id);
_calendarController.CurrentUser = mockCp.Object;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should mock your _userManager, and use a mock setup for when the method FindAsync is called. Then you return a fake user you can use later in the code